# Encryption and authentication issues while trying to add a timestamp to codesigning

Tags: windows, sdk, timestamp, code-signing, signtool

Hy!

I want sign a windows .exe binary with signtool from the Microsoft Platform SDK (7.1) and add a timestamp to the signature. I have two problems with that.

1. The (RFC compliant) timestamp server I want to use only allows encrypted https connections, but the /tr option of signtool returns an error, if the URL is not prefixed by http://
2. I need to authenticate to the timestamp server prior to using it, either by TLS-Client-Authentication (using the signature certificate) or by classic HTTPS username/password login. But I can't find a way to set any of these with signtool.

Is there a way to accomplish this?